# How can I use MySQL GROUP BY modifier WITH ROLLUP in Zend_Db_Select?

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, zend-db-select, rollup

The SQL query in my web application(PHP/MySQL + Zend) uses a number of parameters to build the search query. However, the records fetched should be grouped by two columns to get sub totals. **WITH ROLLUP** seems to be a good solution to find subtotals, but **Zend_Db_Select** doesn't support this modifier. Is there any work around?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well,

```
$select->from(array('t1' => 'table1'))
    ->where("where");
    ->group("(field1)  WITH ROLLUP");
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. Actually I tried the same statement without parenthesis around the field name and it didn't worked.

Comment: Caution: Do not use order() and group("(field1) with rollup")